# How to omit word from a sentence and keep the gist?

Tags: ellipsis, headlinese

In this headline from New York Times,

> F.D.A. Advisory Panel to Discuss Ways of Evolving the U.S. Vaccine Strategy

I feel a complement before 'to discuss' is needed, like this:

> F.D.A. Advisory Panel (is set/ is about) to Discuss Ways of Evolving the U.S. Vaccine Strategy

Is there any rule to omitting words while maintaining the gist (both gramatically and semantically)?

Comment: You should research [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese), which is its own dialect of English.

Comment: @Laurel, pretty very much did